# Angular global class how to implement it?

Tags: css, angular, angular-components

I am very new to Angular and currently I am trying to add styling to an existing project.
The project has been constructed using components.  So for each page there are 4 files,

- mypage.component.css
- mypage.component.html
- mypage.component.spec.ts
- mypage.component.ts

I can easily style the page by adding the styles to the css file in the component and the page style works perfectly.
However the issue is there are many pages that require the same styles again and again.
I can copy and paste the same styles to each css file and it works.
But this is not the most elegant or efficient way to do this.
I want to know what the correct way to add a global.css file so that it can be accessed by each page.  So that way the css is only written once.

I have googled but haven't found anything that explains how to do it in simple ways.

Thanks

Comment: you can add common classes in styles.css or styles.scss on src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular adds the `style.css/scss` file by default to your project once you created it using the `ng new` command, and include it within the `angular.json` config file to be available across the components of the project.

So you can add any global styles within `src/styles.css(or scss)` file, to be implemented everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

you can add your generic css into style.css/style.scss.

Comment: so i have created a global-style.css file with the styles.  How do I add or import this into my component?

Comment: go to angular.json, inside "assets" add the path to your css.